# How can I handle an onsubmit event in a parent component from the button?

Tags: reactjs

In my `Parent` component, there is a form and for submit button it is mentioned in child component.

For example, on hyperlink in the parent component (which is having lots of input data), I'm displaying a popup which is a child component and in this popup there is a submit button, which is also in the child component.

How can I handle `OnSubmit` method of the parent component from the child component's button click?

Answer (score 0):

Did you store and maintain all input data in parent? If No, you need to store input data in parent component (or using Context Api and store data there)

Create handleSubmit in parent component and pass it as a callback function from parent to button click component, when button is clicked, call the callback function to trigger a handleSubmit function in parent.
Simple demo

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  // store all form data in this parent
  const [formData, setFormData]= useState({})

  const handleSubmit=() =>{
    // handle and summit your formData here
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* Crate a Form compoent and render it here */}
      <Button onSubmit={handleSubmit}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export const Button = ({onSubmit}) =>{
  return(
    <button onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</button>
  )
}
```

Comment: yeah, all input data is in parent

Comment: Can you please provide any link having explanation regarding it or any snippet if possible

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution to call parent component function using React props(Property).

[React Property:][1]https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

```js
// Parent Component

import React from "react";
// import child component

class parent extends React.Component{

    parentClassFunction = () => {
        console.log("parent called")
    };

    render(){
       <Child
           parentClassFunction={this.parentClassFunction}
       />
    }
}
export default parent



//    Child Component

class Child extends React.Component{

    onClickSubmitButton = () =>{
      this.props.parentClassFunction()
    };

    render(){
        <button onClick={this.onClickSubmitButton}>CLICK</button>
    }
}
export default Child
```